# Is there a way to reference the value of one css property in another css property?

Tags: html, css

tags seem to have a built-in margin, 8px for Firefox, Chrome, and Safari. While they are all consistent at 8px, it seems like this can change based on the browser vendor.

I want my page to take up 100vw and 100vh including the built-in margin, but am having trouble figuring out how to do this in a way that does not hardcode the margin. For instance:

```
.page-container{
  width: calc(100vw - 16px);
  height: calc(100vh - 16px);
}
```

This will make sure my page fills the view because the container's width + margin-left and margin-right = 100vw exactly, and same with the height. However, this relies on the built-in margin staying the same: 8px on all sides. If this changes for any reason it could make my page overflow or not fill the view.

Is there a way to rewrite this referencing the  margin directly? Something like:

```
.page-container{
  width: calc(100vw - <body>margin-left - <body>margin-right);
  height: calc(100vh - <body>margin-top - <body>margin-bottom);
}
```

I searched w3schools and other css references but couldn't find this.

Comment: How about you just do a reset and remove that margin on the body and html tags?

Comment: I want to make it browser generic and this may give issues with different sized scrollbars based on browsers. I know its unrealistic that a scrollbar will be bigger than, say, 10px, so I'd be safe overriding the margin to that, but aesthetically I want my page + scrollbar to be exactly 100vw

Comment: Are you talking about the browser scroll bar, or an overflow scroll? 100vw will always be 100% of the `viewport` width. You can set the browser margin for every browser by resetting it as well. No reason to try and guess what the browser is doing, change it to your settings.

Comment: I believe the browser scroll bar. If I set the div inside of <body> to width/height of 100vw/100vh it overflows the <body> and creates both horizontal and vertical scroll bars

Comment: Will this work? https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp